# Font file loaded from temp file seems incorrect

Tags: python, pygame

```
for key in fnt.keys():

    str1 = base64.b64decode(fnt[key])
    strA = XOR(str1, coder)

    temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    temp.seek(0)
    temp.write(strA)
    temp.seek(0)

    if key == "calibri.ttf":
        FONT = temp
    if key == "calibrib.ttf":
        FONTB = temp
        temp.close()
return (FONT, FONTB)
```

In the above code I have retrieved fonts saved as a string in a dictionary. When I use this code it returns an error - RuntimeError: Can't seek in stream.
With the code below it works perfectly. Someone please explain how to use the temp file method to get the fonts rather than write to file. Is that possible?

```
for key in fnt.keys():

    str1 = base64.b64decode(fnt[key])
    strA = XOR(str1, coder)

    with open(home + "\\" + key, "wb") as to_disk:
        to_disk.write(strA)
        FONT = "calibri.ttf"
        FONTB = "calibrib.ttf"

return (FONT, FONTB)
```

I am adding the full code below. See if this helps in giving me a viable answer.

```
import string
import base64
import os
from fnt import fnt
import string
import tempfile
from itertools import cycle, izip

def XOR(message, key):
    cryptedMessage = ''.join(chr(ord(c)^ord(k)) for c,k in izip(message, cycle(key)))

    return cryptedMessage

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    """extracts and returns the font files from fnt.py"""
    coder ="PHdzDER+@k7pcm!LX8gufh=y9A^UaMsn-oW6"
    home = os.getcwd()
    for key in fnt.keys():

        str1 = base64.b64decode(fnt[key])
        strA = XOR(str1, coder)

        #temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
        #temp.seek(0)
        #temp.write(strA)
        #temp.seek(0)


        #if key == "calibri.ttf":
            #FONT = temp

        #if key == "calibrib.ttf":
            #FONTB = temp


        with open(home + "\\" + key, "wb") as to_disk:
            to_disk.write(strA)
            FONT = "calibri.ttf"
            FONTB = "calibrib.ttf"

    return (FONT, FONTB)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What Python version, what OS, and what type does XOR return (I only ask because I don't recall XOR being a Python function)? As well what line does it say the error is occurring?

Comment: What is FONT and FONTB suppose to contain. A file object or a file name? I think what is occurring is that you are returning File objects in the first code snippet and filenames in the second. In the first you close the file as well. Later on if you try to access it you won't be able to seek on a closed stream

Comment: @Michael Petch, Python version is 2.7.8 running on Windows 7 64bit. XOR is a declared function which does this:               cryptedMessage = ''.join(chr(ord(c)^ord(k)) for c,k in izip(message, cycle(key)))

Comment: FONT and FONTB loads the font file written to disk by the statement above it. fnt is a dictionary which holds "calibri.ttf" and calibrib.ttf" as a string. I extract it from the dictionary with the above two routines but the font file is recognized only when itis written to disk and then read back.

Comment: Hopefully, the code I added to my answer does what you want, or close to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When temp is closed it is destroyed, so you won't be able to read from it to extract the font data.

On what line of your code do you get the `RuntimeError: Can't seek in stream` error message? As Michael Petch said, we need to know your OS. tempfile.TemporaryFile() is certainly seekable on Linux.

BTW, in

```
if key == "calibrib.ttf":
    FONTB = temp
    temp.close()
```

The `temp.close()` is inside the `if` block. I guess that might just be a copy & paste error. But as I said above, you **don't** want to close these files until you've read from them.

Presumably, your original font reading function opens the font files from disk with the filenames and then accesses the font data using the file handle from `open()`. So as Michael Petch said, you need to change that to accept handles from files that are already open.

### **EDIT**

I got confused earlier when you said that "There is NO other font reading function", since I couldn't figure out what you were actually trying to do with the decrypted font data.

And I guess I also got confused by you calling your font extraction function `main()`, since main() is conventionally used as the entry-point into a program, so a program normally doesn't run a bunch of different `main()` functions in different modules.

Anyway...

I've never used pygame, but from a quick look at [the docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) you can give `pygame.font.Font()` either a font name string or an open font filehandle as the first arg, eg

`myfont = pygame.font.Font(font_filehandle, size)`

Presumably your `fnt` module has a dict containing two strings of base64 encoded, XOR-encrypted font data, keyed by the font names, "calibrib.ttf".

So this *should* work, assuming I'm not misunderstanding that pygame doc. :)

**Warning: Untested code**

```
def xor_str(message, key):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(c)^ord(k)) for c,k in izip(message, cycle(key))])

def decode_fonts(fnt):
    coder = "PHdzDER+@k7pcm!LX8gufh=y9A^UaMsn-oW6"

    font_fh = {}
    for key in fnt.keys():
        xorfont = base64.b64decode(fnt[key])

        temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
        temp.write(xor_str(xorfont, coder))
        temp.seek(0)

        font_fh[key] = temp
    return font_fh

#...............

    #In your pygame function:
    font_fh = decode_fonts(fnt)

    font_obj = {}
    for key in font_fh.keys():
        font_obj[key] = pygame.font.Font(font_fh[key], point_size)

    #Now you can do
    surface = font_obj["calibri.ttf"].render(text, antialias, color, background=None)
```

Comment: There is NO other font reading function. I removed the temp.close(). That was by mistake. Still no change.

Comment: Firstly, returning a tuple of font names from `main()` is weird: `main()` is supposed to return an integer. And how do you expect to get fonts out of `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` files?

Comment: The exact implementation of tempfiles is OS-dependant. (They *might* be regular files or fake files that the kernel manages (eg in a RAM disk); on Linux they're files on the hard disk whose directory entry is removed as soon as the files are created to make them inaccessible to other processes). But regardless of the details they are supposed to be destroyed by the OS as soon as they are closed. So there's no way another process (even the OS) can access your decoded fonts. So just stick with what works.

Comment: currently I am sticking with what works. But I will try StringIO and BytesIO too. Can you please explain why is it that main() is supposed to return an integer? Is it ONLY an integer and nothing else?

Comment: So are you saying that if I write a program to convert an English string to say Swahili and I enclose the program in def main(): and call it with if __name__=='__main__': ant the program returns the translated string in Swahili it is NOT CORRECT(to do that)??

Comment: Exactly. `main()` **only** returns the program's exit status to the OS, which is a small(ish) integer. But of course `main()` can _print_ a string to stdout (or stderr), or write it to a file.

Comment: If it can write it to a file what is wrong in returning it if it's the same data? I don't get this "Can't do this" logic". I have a module in which there is a function which returns an image, or a wave file from a dictionary at termination and it has worked perfectly. What is wrong with that?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that! Because that function is passing its result to some other function inside your program. But when your program _as a whole_ returns anything it returns gets passed to the shell. And shells only expect integer return codes, as explained in the Wiki article I linked. What OS are you using? In *nix you can see the return code of the last program you ran in a shell by `echo $?`.

Comment: Actually, I was a bit wrong. `return` from `main()` (or whatever your outermost function is) in Python just gets ignored, and your script **always** returns 0 to the OS. The behaviour I was talking about before applies to C, and other compiled languages, though. To get Python to return a number to the OS you have to call `sys.exit()` or `exit()`. Sorry about that misinformation.

Comment: That's ok. Your enthusiasm in answering and helping someone overshadows trivial mistakes. :) I am using windows and the above code is one module out of many. I tried many methods but found that Pygame needs to read fonts from disk.

Comment: @Wookie : Excellent! We got there in the end. :)

Comment: There is something that still isn't write when it runs in a loop. It prints once to the screen but the second time around it gives a "RuntimeError: Can't seek in stream". Do I have to ask in another question?

Comment: When what runs in a loop? You call decode_fonts() and pass the temp font filehandles to `pygame.font.Font(font_fh[key], point_size)` which should load the font so you can use render with it. But if you attempt to pass that temp filehandle to `pygame.font.Font()` *again* it's likely to fail, since `pygame.font.Font()` probably closes the temp file once it's loaded the font data. And as you know, you can't read from a `close()`d file.

Comment: True. But isn't it possible to hold the data somewhere where it can be accessed repeatedly in a loop rather than always calling decode_fonts()? Decode the fonts once and hold the data somewhere so that it can be accessed without calling the main routine? Maybe make a copy?

Comment: Sure! But `pygame.font.Font()` wants to see a file-like object, and it will close that file-like object every time. So you need to save the string data that you've decoded from base46 and XORed. And then wrap a copy of it in some kind of file-like object each time you need to feed it to `pygame.font.Font()`. Alternatively, store a copy of the font object that `pygame.font.Font()` if you want to re-use that font.

Comment: As an alternative to using `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` check out the `io` and `StringIO` modules. IIRC, `StringIO` is deprecated, so `io` is probably the best choice. And if you have problems working with them, start a new question.