# saving font data in memory

Tags: python, pygame

This question is related to this one. [Font file loaded from temp file seems incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856065/font-file-loaded-from-temp-file-seems-incorrect/25859560?noredirect=1#comment40579377_25859560).

Pygame seem to have the habit of closing the font file after reading but when it's on disk thats ok as it can be read over and over again. How can we save the read font data to memory so that it can be recalled any number of times but does not loose its format? In this case the data saved to disk should remain as a FILE OBJECT? I have tried deepcopy without success. The code given below

```
def xor(message, key):
    cryptedMessage = ''.join(chr(ord(c)^ord(k)) for c,k in izip(message, cycle(key)))

    return cryptedMessage

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def decode_fonts(fnt = fnt):

    """extracts and returns the font files from fnt.py in a dictionary"""
    coder = "QZY0r[CIlVwq1O#SxBt_2eij%b;3$vJK4,FN&TG5PHdzDER+@k7pcm!LX8gufh=y9A^UaMsn-oW6"
    font_fh = {}
    font_obj = {}
    point_size = 5

    for key in fnt.keys():

        xorfont = base64.b64decode(fnt[key])

        tempbuffer = StringIO()
        tempbuffer.write(xor(xorfont, coder))
        tempbuffer.seek(0)
        font_fh[key] = tempbuffer
        #print type(temp), type(font_fh)

    for key in font_fh.keys():
        font_obj[key] = pygame.font.Font(font_fh[key], point_size)


    return font_fh, font_obj
```

on the printing side

```
font_fh, font_obj = gs.fontstore.decode_fonts()

def maketext(msg, fontsize, colour, bgcolour, underline, FONTNAME):
    """returns the text supplied as an image with x and y diamentions of the image"""

    mafont = font_obj[FONTNAME]
    font_fh[FONTNAME].seek(0)
    mafont = pygame.font.Font(font_fh[FONTNAME], fontsize)

    mafont.set_underline(underline)

    fontxy = mafont.size(msg)  # get image size x, y for print formatting

    if bgcolour is None:

        matext = mafont.render(msg, True, colour)
    else:
        matext = mafont.render(msg, True, colour, bgcolour)

    matext = matext.convert_alpha()

    return [matext, fontxy]

    text1 = maketext(msg1, 40, WHITE, None, False, FONT1)
    text2 = maketext(msg2, 40, WHITE, None, False, FONT2)
    text3 = maketext(msg2, 40, WHITE, None, False, FONT3)
    text4 = maketext(msg2, 40, WHITE, None, False, FONT4)
    text5 = maketext(msg2, 40, WHITE, None, False, FONT5)
    text6 = maketext(msg2, 40, WHITE, None, False, FONT6)


    def update_all():
        SCREEN.fill((BLACK))
        SCREEN.blit(text1[0], (0, 0))
        SCREEN.blit(text2[0], (0, 50))
        SCREEN.blit(text3[0], (0, 100))
        SCREEN.blit(text4[0], (0, 150))
        SCREEN.blit(text5[0], (0, 200))
        SCREEN.blit(text6[0], (0, 250))


        pygame.display.update()

    def get_keys():
        global run
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            MOUSEPOS = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            if event.type is KEYDOWN:
                if event.key is K_ESCAPE:
                    run = False

    while run:

        clock.tick(60)
        get_keys()
        #text6 = maketext(msg2, 40, WHITE, None, False, FONT6)

        update_all()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

This works perfectly BUT if I uncomment the '#text6 = maketext(msg2, 40, WHITE, None, False, FONT6)' line in the while loop the program halts throwing the error

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Need support on this please.

Comment: Why do you care? Just read the font once and keep a reference to the `pygame.font.Font` and you don't need to read the font file again.

Comment: True, But that reference points to stringIO location which is referenced by font data loaded from a dictionary stored in a pyfile. There is NO font on disk in any conventional way. So once it is read the file is closed and I have to go through the entire process again to get the font. That is what i am trying to avoid.

Comment: Look at the code: Every time you call `maketext`, you create a new `Font` instance. Why don't simply cache the instance instead of creating the font from scratch every time?

Answer (score 0):

After considering the advice above the below code was sucessful.
moved the font build routine to a separate function.

```
    def makefont(FONTNAME, fontsize):
        """the font type and size given the custom made font is returned"""

        encryptedfont = base64.b64decode(fntdata[FONTNAME])

        tempbuffer = StringIO()
        tempbuffer.write(XOR(encryptedfont, coder))
        tempbuffer.seek(0)

        madefont = pygame.font.Font(tempbuffer, fontsize)

        return madefont

def maketext(msg, colour, bgcolour, underline, madefont):
    """returns the text supplied as an image with x and y diamentions of the image"""

    madefont.set_underline(underline)

    fontxy = madefont.size(msg)  # get image size x, y for print formatting

    if bgcolour is None:

        matext = madefont.render(msg, True, colour)
    else:
        matext = madefont.render(msg, True, colour, bgcolour)

    matext = matext.convert_alpha()

    return [matext, fontxy]
```

call the `maketext()` when i need to change font size, else `maketext` reuses `madefont` from previous time.